# Score on testing set - Text mining

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, text-mining, logistic-regression

I try to print accurancy score after score validation. Score validation is equal to 82%. But the accuracy score is equal to 0 ...

```
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5)
grille=grid.fit(text_train, Y_train)
y_pred = grille.predict(text_test)
from sklearn import metrics
#matrice de confusion
print("matrice confusion")
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(Y_test,y_pred))
#succès en test
print("score accuracy")
print(metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test,y_pred))
```

When I print confusion matrix :

```
 [[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   27    2]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   88   23]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   12    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   22    4]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  108   90]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   28   60]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   16   94]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   49  424]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    5   76]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   78 1487]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]]
```

I don't understand why.. and what is the format of my matrix (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 27)

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for [confusion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) and [accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html).

Very simply, the confusion matrix claims that all of the validation inputs were in classes 0-9, but incorrectly identified as class 10 or 11.

Since you failed to provide the canonical [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I have no way to work on the problem past this point.  Please update this with code that reproduces the problem.